# Is PDP visualization appropriate for binary variables in XGBoost?

Tags: xgboost, pdp

If it's a binary variable, like 1 or 0, is it suitable to use PDP (Partial Dependence Plots) for visualization? What type of graph should I use?

Previously, I've only used PDP visualization for continuous and multi-class variable features. I'm wondering if it can also be applied to binary variables.